# Merge two images of different sizes leaves black color in a smaller image

Tags: c#, image-processing, image-manipulation

I am using C#.   I've two images as following:

Image1: 200 X 100
Image2: 200 X 200

I tried merging it with Canvas, Graphics and Pixel methods and all work but with a glitch that it leaves black color in that 100 pixel area of image1 height.

I prefer to have that area as complete transparent instead of black color.

Here's the url for the merged image I'm referring to:
[Image Url](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/46635bf4ad.jpg)

I highly appreciate your pointers on this.  Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Impossible to guess, post code.

Answer (score 0):

I was saving the final image as .jpg and that was creating that issue.  I then saved it in .png and bingo, problem is solved.

Many thanks folks!